# Changing parametric form to Cartesian form; $x = t + \cos \frac{t}{k}$; $y = -\sin \frac{t}{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to eliminate $t$ from, $$ x = t + \cos \frac{t}{k} $$ and $$y = -\sin \frac{t}{k}$$
to get an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$ only. Essentially, I am trying to convert it from parametric form to Cartesian form.
Please help, I am stuck. :(

**Update!**
Please do this without the use of inverse trigonometric function i.e. don't put any restrictions on the value of $t$. This is the equation of the path of a particle on a moving wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos {t\over k} = x-t$$
$$\sin {t\over k} = -y$$
$$t = -k\sin^{-1} y\quad(t\in\left[{-k\pi/2},{k\pi/2}\right])$$
$$(x-t)^2+(-y)^2=(x+k\sin^{-1} y)^2+y^2=1$$

---

Removing $\sin^{-1}$:
$$\sin^{-1} y={\pm\sqrt{1-y^2} - x\over k }$$
$$y=\sin\left({\pm\sqrt{1-y^2} - x\over k }\right)$$

Comment: You should probably mention that this only holds for $t \in [-k\pi/2, k\pi/2]$, as that is the range of $\arcsin$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, I added it.

Comment: I am sorry but I wanted this to be done without the use of $\sin^{-1}$ as this is the equation of the path of a point on a moving wheel of radius $k$.

Comment: @xXLemonProgrammerXx Okay, done.

Comment: @KayK.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @xXLemonProgrammerXx Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$\cos\frac{t}{k}=x-t$$$$\implies \cos^2\frac{t}{k}=(x-t)^2\tag 1$$
$$\sin\frac{t}{k}=-y$$$$\implies \sin^2\frac{t}{k}=(-y)^2\tag 2$$
Now, adding (1) & (2), one should get 
$$\cos^2\frac{t}{k}+\sin^2\frac{t}{k}=(x-t)^2+(-y)^2$$ $$(x-t)^2+y^2=1$$
$$\color{}{x^2+y^2-2tx+t^2-1=0}$$
now, substituting $t=-k\sin^{-1}(y)$,  $$\color{red}{x^2+y^2+2kx\sin^{-1}(y)+k^2(\sin^{-1}(y))^2-1=0}$$

$\forall\ \ \ \ -1\le y\le 1$

Comment: $t$ is still present. Is this normal ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $t$ is not present in the equation(red). Removing that $t$ is our goal!

Comment: Yes, so we have removed $t$ in the final result. You can check it

Comment: That is fine now ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate $(t/k)$ with $sin/cos$ giving $ (x-t)^2 + y^2 =1 $ which still contains $t.$ So plug in $ t=-k\sin^{-1}(y)$ to eliminate $t$ resulting in:

$$(x+k\sin^{-1}(y))^2 + y^2 =1, $$

a situation similar to a cycloid with a $y$ scaling.